# How to block selected characters in simple register Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem  with simple registration in Django. When the user will write  at the first registration the username with '.' or @, for example 'User.Name' my internet application returns error like this 'NoReverseMatch at /'

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'reviews',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\projrkt22.08-20.00\env\my_app\winerama\templates\base.html, error at line 50
   Reverse for 'user_review_list' with arguments '('aleksandra.franiczek',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['review/user/$', 'review/user/(?P<username>\\w+)/$']
   40 :               </div>
   41 :               <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
   42 :                 <h4 class="text-white">Nawigacja</h4>
   43 :                 <ul class="list-unstyled">
   44 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:home' %}" class="text-white">Strona główna</a></li>
   45 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_list' %}" class="text-white">Lista produktów</a></li>
   46 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}" class="text-white">Najnowsze opinie</a></li>
   47 :                 </ul>
   48 :                 <ul class="list-unstyled">
   49 :                   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   50 :                   <li><a href=" {% url 'reviews:user_review_list' user.username %} " class="text-white">Witaj {{ user.username }}</a></li>
   51 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:user_recommendation_list' %}" class="text-white">Sugerowane produkty</a></li>
   52 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="text-white">Wyloguj</a></li>
   53 :                   {% else %}
   54 :                   <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="text-white">Logowanie</a></li>
   55 :                   <li><a href="/accounts/register" class="text-white">Rejestracja</a></li>
   56 :                   {% endif %}
   57 :                 </ul>
   58 :               </div>
   59 :             </div>
   60 :           </div>


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\projrkt22.08-20.00\env\my_app\winerama\reviews\views.py" in review_list
  13.     return render(request, 'reviews/review_list.html', context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  636.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'user_review_list' with arguments '('aleksandra.franiczek',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['review/user/$', 'review/user/(?P<username>\\w+)/$']
```

when the user will be removed from the database in django admin everything works well. 
How can I block use of these marks upon first registration (in my situation)?

**my file_registration.html looks like this**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container marketing">
    <form method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          {% bootstrap_icon "user" %} Register
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    path('reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'reviews',
    'registration'
]

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # One-week activation window
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True # Automatically log the user in.



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'winerama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'winerama.wsgi.application'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/reviews/review/user'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reviews/media')
```

**urls.py app**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .import views

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /
    url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    #Home
    url(r'^home/', views.frond_photo_list, name='home'),
    #Blog
    url(r'^blog/', views.blog_list, name='blog'),
    # ex: /review/5/
    url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    # ex: /wine/
    url(r'^wine$', views.wine_list, name='wine_list'),
    # ex: /wine/5/
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.wine_detail, name='wine_detail'),
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review'),
    url(r'^review/user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
    url(r'^review/user/$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
    # ex: /recommendation - get wine recommendations for the logged user
    url(r'^recommendation/$', views.user_recommendation_list, name='user_recommendation_list'),
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you add **`include('reviews.urls')`** two times in your `url`?

Comment: I added this because it made my job easier. When I entered on my local host 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' I was redirected to my websites (
where I worked)

Comment: Can you add the `reviews.urls` module ?

Comment: of course, I added urls.py my application

Comment: To block unwanted characters use field validation. To use user input as URL part slugify it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular expression **`[@\w+.]+`** instead of **`\w+`** in **`user_review_list`** url.

So, change

```
url(r'^review/user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
```

to

```
url(r'^review/user/(?P<username>[@\w+.]+)/$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
```